Invalid Type compilation error when I am trying to initialize vlocity_ins.DRProcessResult to invoke a load DataMapper from Apex
I am trying to invoke a load DataMapper from an apex class and when I try to initialize vlocity_ins.ProcessResult to invoke the DataMapper I am running into an Invalid type error on compilation in dev console.
            String dataJson = JSON.serialize(ipOutput.get('data'));
            vlocity_ins.DRProcessResult result = vlocity_ins.DRGlobal.processObjectsJSON(dataJson, 'CreateWorkOrder');
            Map<String, Object> resultMap = result.convertToMap();
            System.debug(JSON.serialize(resultMap)); 

The invalid type error just says: 'Invalid type: vlocity_ins.DRProcessResult'.
All my research has led me to was the salesforce help docs article on how to invoke the load datamapper: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.os_dataraptor_calls_from_apex_47779.htm&type=5 which wasn't too helpful unfortunately. I checked installed packages and Omnistudio is installed, so I'm not sure why I am getting this error on compilation. Thank you for your time and let me know I can add any more information here to help get to an answer.

One of my coworkers informed me that at some point when velocity had changed names to omnistudio, they also updated their naming conventions for their components and what I was missing was just the fact that instead of appending the DRProcessResult with vlocity_ins, I needed to append it with omnistudio:
vlocity_ins.DRProcessResult ---> omnistudio.DRProcessResult
That changed fixed this error and I hope that anyone else that may run into this issue will find this thread, because I could not find any documentation regarding this change anywhere.

You should post this as an answer, not as a comment; this way community knows there is an accepted answer

Writing my own answer because OP hasn't made their own in nearly 2 weeks.
The help article seems to omit an important detail. From the documentation on DRGlobal Class and Methods we see this little gem

In all the method signatures shown below, the namespace is omnistudio, vlocity_cmt, vlocity_ins, or vlocity_ps. The bundleName is the Data Mapper name.

So vlocity_ins.DRProcessResult result = vlocity_ins.DRGlobal.processObjectsJSON(dataJson, 'CreateWorkOrder'); may be correct for some people.
Since it appears that all forms of Omnistudio are managed packages, the namespace you need to use will depend on whatever "Namespace Prefix" you see when you find Ominstudio in Setup -> Apps -> Packaging -> Installed Apps.
In OP's particular case, the Namespace Prefix was omnistudio, so omnistudio.DRProcessResult result = omnistudio.DRGlobal.processObjectsJSON(dataJson, 'CreateWorkOrder'); was correct for them.
